# "Tie" uploaded image to the rest

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, image, upload

I have a form and the person who fill it has the option to upload an image. The information is then stored in a table, with the person's name, e-mail, etc. and later shown in a page for the admin. I'm able to pull all the information, except I don't know how to store the image into the database and show it for the admin later. Hope you guys could understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't store the images in the database, you store there path as a string

There is global variable called `$_FILES` just as `$_GET` and `$_POST` that contains all the info on the files uploaded. These are first stored in a temp directory. You use `move_uploaded_files` function to move them to a proper place. Then save the string in database.

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads'; // Directory where you want to upload/keep all your pictures
// Lets assume you sent the picture in `pictures` name field of form
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
       // Save `$upload_dir/$name` in db
    }
}
?>
```

Now when you want to load the image later, just query the column of the table that stores the images location and use it as `src` at frontend.

Comment: That's what I mean't, to be stored as a path. Sorry for my bad english, It's not my main language. I'm sorry I can't vote up your answer, but If It's any worth you really helped me

Comment: @MateusGuimarães You can atleast accept the answer

Comment: I'm able to get the directory to the database, however the image is not getting uploaded. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Check php error logs for better details, rest I think mostly it would have occurred due to folder permissions on the path where you are uploading, it should www-data writable